# What's the meaning of starting with :: Rust macro

Tags: rust

I saw macro coding right below.

Why should **::**  be first of the statement and what does it mean?

::std::collections::HashMap::new()

```
macro_rules! hashmap {
    () => {
        {
            ::std::collections::HashMap::new()
        }
    };
    ($($k:expr => $v:expr),*) => {
        {
            let mut _map = ::std::collections::HashMap::new();
            $(_map.insert($k, $v);)*
            _map
        }
    };
    ($($k:expr => $v:expr),+ $(,)?) => {
        {
            let mut _map = ::std::collections::HashMap::new();
            $(_map.insert($k, $v);)*
            _map
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path starting with `::` means that search in global namespace. Since @Chayin already pointed the documentation, A example might be useful for you and future readers.
When you run this program:
**test-program/src/main**

```rust
mod std {
    pub mod f64 {
        pub mod consts {
            pub const PI: f64 = 4.0;
        }
    }
}

macro_rules! test_mactro {
    () => {{
        pub mod std { pub mod f64 { pub mod consts {
            pub const PI: f64 = 5.0;
        }}}

        println!("{}", std::f64::consts::PI);
        println!("{}", ::std::f64::consts::PI);
        println!("{}", self::std::f64::consts::PI);
    }};
}

fn main() {
    test_mactro!()
}
```

And see the output:

```
$ cargo run
5
3.141592653589793
4
```

Comment: Thanks, it's useful in order to understand more concisely !!

Answer (score 3):

It means "search in the global namespace". See [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/paths.html#path-qualifiers).

It basically means (in edition 2018 and beyond) to not search in this crate. Suppose we were using unqualified `std::collections::HashMap` (without the leading `::`), and the macro was used in a module that defines a `std` submodule, like that:

```rust
mod std;

hashmap! {}
```

In this case, the declared `std` module will take precedence over the preexisting `std` library, and the macro will refer to it. Of course there isn't a `collections::HashMap` in there (or worse, there is but it is different from the expected `HashMap`). To prevent that, we use `::std` and that means "search for a *crate* named `std`, **do not** look for modules with that name".

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know what keyword shoud be searching.